# Inject variables with a secret value in Bamboo

Tags: bamboo, secret-key

Currently I am updating my plans to start using bamboo-yaml specs. However I do have variables I use in a lot of plans and want to create an `inject-variables`-task to import this list. As this list contains usernames and passwords I'd like to use the Bamboo encryption for these variables. However the injection seems to work, but not the decryption on Bamboo's end.

Can someone help me out or tell me what I do wrong.

task:

```
- inject-variables:
   file: variables.conf
   scope: LOCAL
   namespace: inject
```

inject variables file;

```
env_password="BAMSCRT@RANDOMSTRING"
env_username="user"
```

Therefor I need to use `${bamboo.inject.env_password}` in the script later on. But it seems to pass along the string "BAMSCRT@RANDOMSTRING" instead of the decrypted password

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. At least for bamboo 7.2 which I am using, this seems to be a missing feature. If you, however, add the variables in the specs file not injecting them at all, everything works as expected.

```
---
version: 2
plan:
  ....
variables:
  env_password: BAMSCRT@RANDOMSTRING
  env_username: user
```

The idea behing the inject variables features seems to be having variables that change in before committing your code, e.g. a version counter.

Answer (score -2):

append **_secret** in your variable with encrypted content.

in your inject file:

```
env_password_secret="BAMSCRT@RANDOMSTRING"
```

Comment: I am no longer working in a bamboo project but if someone could verify this, that would be awesome. Normally password is also treated as a secret value.

Comment: And where to get that "RANDOMSTRING" from?!

Comment: @mbo use https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-specs-encryption-970268127.html to encrypt your string